# Xcode Bots Won't Build Without SSL Certs

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode-server

I recently transferred my MacOS continuous integration server from a MacBook Air to a MacMini (using Migration Assistant) and while all my settings seemed to carry over fine, whenever I run one of my Bots, I gets errors about missing certificates. I've tried everything (adding self-signed certificates, etc.) but to no avail. I even tried deleting the Server app and reinstalling it from the AppStore but that still didn't help. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after many days, I finally figured it out. First, I wouldn't have had any issues if I had just done a clean install on my MacMini but hindsight is 20/20. The solution was to rm -rf the /Library/Server directory (you'll need to sudo su before you do this). That directory contains all the settings for the MacOS Server and it remains even after deleting Server.app. By deleting Server.app, deleting this directory, and then installing Server.app again, you force Server.app to properly regen all the proper certs, etc.

Yes, you'll have to recreate your Bots and repo links but at least it will all work!